# If weak isospin is not conserved in time, what does the Noether theorem tell us?

Tags: conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, electroweak, chirality, isospin-symmetry

As far as I understand [weak isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) is only conserved in interactions but not as time evolves. Nevertheless, we get from Noethers theorem, because of global $SU(2)$ invariance a *conserved* quantity that is commonly called weak isospin (see for example [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149324/)).

I have never read the explicit statement that weak isospin is violated as time evolves (= during propagation), but chirality is not conserved as time evolves (see for example [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131333/)) and left-chiral particles carry isospin, whereas right-chiral do not. Therefore it follows from the non-conservance of chirality that isospin isn't conserved either.

**How does this fit together with the result of Noether's theorem?**

Comment: Interesting question. Note that in the usual formulation Noether's theorem applies to continuous symmetries, while isospin is a discrete symmetry.

Comment: @rob: Why would isospin be discrete? It is $\mathrm{SU}(2)$!

Comment: To OP: The isospin current, and hence the charge, is not conserved because the isospin $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is *broken* (by the Higgs mechanism)! For details, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33917/50583).

Comment: Weak isospin is the SM $SU(2)_L$, and its current is absolutely conserved--otherwise it would not couple to the corresponding gauge fields consistently! It is *not* an anomalous symmetry. Since the symmetry is spontaneously broken, the currents evince the Nambu-Goldstone realization mode, which makes the Higgs mechanism possible. What you may *misconstrue* as WI breaking is probably failure to account for Goldstone and Higgs degrees of freedom absorbed into weak singlets observed in the lab.  Provide a concrete example to deconstruct: Coupling to the R-fermion  singlet involves the Higgs vev.