# Do conservation laws still hold for spontaneously broken symmetries?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, noethers-theorem

For a given gauge symmetry $G$, we get via Noether's theorem conservation laws

$$   \partial_\mu j^\mu = 0 . $$

Do these conservation laws still hold, when $G$ gets broken spontaneously through a non-zero vacuum expecation value of some scalar field?

Comment: Why do you think they'd still hold?  Also, question of whether Ward identities stilll hold after ssb very relevant here

Comment: @innisfree I'm currently trying to understand the famous no-go theorems (Coleman-Mandula's, Haag–Lopuszanski–Sohnius'). Their argument is that when we put the internal symmetry group and the Poincare group in some larger group, we get additional conservation laws. These addtional conservation laws overconstrain the S-matrix in such a way that no interactions are possible, i.e. the S-matrix is trivial in such theories. I'm trying to figure out to what extend this argument holds for broken symmetries.

Comment: ***Of course they do***, cf [Goldstone's argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson).  However, the conventional step in parlaying current conservation to time-invariant charges fails by Picasso's thm (in that WP article) on account  of infrared troubles. It is this very persistence of current conservation that endows SSB with its miraculous properties! A SB symmetry is just the same symmetry realized in the nonlinear Nambu-Goldstone mode, but it is magnificently still present, albeit hidden.

Comment: As far as I understand the proof of Coleman-Mandula, it doesn't hold for spontaneously broken symmetries. See the comment here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem#Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking . Coming to you question: of course the conservation equation for the current holds; the variation of a field under an infinitesimal transformation, i.e. the commutator with the conserved charge $Q$ exists too. But $Q$ isn't well defined on the Hilbert space unless $Q|0\rangle=0$, which isn't the case by assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The takeaway, since this question keeps being asked and answered, in several forms,  e.g.  [33917](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/does-spontanous-symmetry-breaking-affect-noethers-theorem),[150644](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150644/if-weak-isospin-is-not-conserved-in-time-what-does-the-noether-theorem-tell-us), and is at the heart of the [Goldstone theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson):

- In SSB, the current is conserved, $   \partial_\mu j^\mu = 0$, as you wrote, and does crucial yeomanly work--that is why one is interested in SSB theories, to start with. The current starts out as *linear* as opposed to the normal bilinear, in the fields, so goes like $j_\mu = -v^2 \partial_\mu \phi ~$ for U(1), for instance. This means the goldstons *shift* under the related symmetry transformation, and so can push into and out of the nontrivial vacuum.
- But the corresponding Noether charge is not well-defined, so its time derivative is also ill defined, and not vanishing, 
  as per the Fabry-Picasso theorem--an infrared phenomenon. So ${d\over dt} Q = {d\over dt} \int_x J^0(x) \neq 0 $ because *Q* itself is not meaningful.
  (So using it in the C-M theorem is definitely unwarranted.)
- You may live dangerously and utilize conservation of the unbroken charge in the lagrangian, as, e.g. in [149324](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149324/why-is-only-the-third-component-of-weak-isospin-used-as-a-conserved-quantity), but you must ensure neither the Higgs that effects SSB nor its consequences (in fermion masses) are present in the terms involved. It is highly dangerous and contraindicated to novices.